# Css styles are not reflecting in my react application

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I have used one component file called xyx.js and I imported my scss file properly './xyz.scss' both are in the same folder. When I see the styles from the chrome scss extension it works however when I tried to see it from my scss file it's not working.Can anyone help me to get through this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

your global SASS file should be imported inside the index.js  file or else it won't work, and you may have to change the global CSS file into SASS and same import the in-app component.